# How hide tilte, decriptions, change url when I shared link to facebook like this? Thanks

Tags: facebook, url

How hide tilte, decriptions, change url when I shared link to facebook like this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyDAh.png

When I click the image, it leads to new.
How can I do this?

Thanks

The intruction to help us do that.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook takes the data from the Open Graph tags in the page source. If you want to redirect to another website, you can do so with JavaScript - Facebook does not parse JavaScript.

I would not advise doing this though, people should know where they go before they click on a link - and not be redirected somewhere else.